# WebMatrix Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'

Tags: javascript, attributes, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix to build my website, and I am stealing some components from the Bakery template.  Specifically, I am trying to load some .js files. by using the script tag.  Here is the exact code I am pulling from the Bakery template that works great:

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

The problem is when I pull it into my page which is still in WebMtrix, I the script tag is underlined with the error message: Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'.

Why would I be getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

In HTML 4 the `type` attribute is required. In HTML 5 it's optional, and defaults to `text/javascript`. Maybe there's a setting in WebMatrix that disables this check.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 that was set to the Optional, however if its asking for it, then you can set the `type=""` property of the script element.

```
@section Scripts {
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

Now it would be a Legal HTML and WebMatrix won't bother asking for anything again.